# Create filter if body of message contains my name

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have a couple on-going conversation threads in Gmail with a number of different people. Is there a way to setup a filter so that it will add a label if the body of any new, unread email contains my name? Then remove the label once I've read the email?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that you can use any [Gmail search operator in a filter](http://lifehacker.com/166172/gmail-search-operators-work-in-filters-too) via the `Has the words:` textbox since Gmail just AND's together the operators that are filled in via the filter dialog.

I'll suggest you start by trying this:

1. Create a filter that finds new emails with your name in them and applies a temporary label. The search operation you would use in the filter is:

   ```
   is:unread AND body:"Your Name"
   ```
2. Create a filter that finds read emails in the temporary label and removes the label.

   ```
   label:templabel AND is:read
   ```

   Unfortunately, while filters *can* operate on read emails, they cannot currently remove labels, we are at a stopping point.

-

Sorry can't help more, but until Gmail filters can remove a label, you will not be able to accomplish this via filters.

Potential workarounds would be:

1. Setup an IMAP client with the equivalent filtering where instead of adding/removing a temporary label you would be copying/deleting the email from the temporary folder.
2. Google recently introduced a [new scripting framework for Google Apps](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/).
3. One really crude hack for step 2 would be to have the filter forward the email as well as delete it. You would forward to your own email address with a plus extension, e.g. `username+templabelname@gmail.com`.

   Then a new step 3 would be to catch those emails using the `deliveredto:username+templabel@gmail.com` search string, and reapply some label.

   Not sure how cleanly this method would work, especially because you would get header cruft from the forward (vs. redirecting).

Personally, I would look at #2 since learning scripting for Google Apps would pay off in the long run.

Comment: there is no "body" field in gmail https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190

Answer (score 11):

There is no [search operator](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7190) to restrict to the body of a message. I would recommend setting up a filter with your name in the "Has the words" field, and apply the label as your action. There is no need to add "is:unread" because filters apply to incoming messages.

Likewise you cannot remove the label via filter or take automatic action after the message has arrived. But there are a few other options that might help:

- Use [keyboard shortcuts](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6594) to remove the label when you finish reading the message. Assuming you are reading the messages from label view, "y" will remove the label, and "[" and "]" will remove the label and move you to the next or previous message.
- Use the [Hide read labels](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/09/new-in-labs-hide-read-labels.html) lab to hide the label if there are no unread messages inside.

Finally, you could also consider setting up a [Quick Link](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=145401) or a [Multiple Inbox](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/02/new-in-labs-multiple-inboxes.html) with the search query: **is:unread yourname**. The link or inbox would automatically update and remove messages from the view after you read them.

Comment: hi, is there a way to match/search names in a spreadsheet with the content/body

Answer (score 1):

The first part: adding a label based on existing keyword is simple, but the second part I think is impossible, because there is no such trigger in Gmail that could cause a filtering operation once an e-mail is read.